# Bridging MQTT AWS to Local Mosquitto, using Windows. And anyone have a working setup?

Tags: openssl, mqtt, mosquitto, aws-iot

I got this following error when bridging mqtt aws to local mosquitto.

```
1573639924: mosquitto version 1.6.7 starting
1573639924: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
1573639924: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1573639924: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1573639924: Bridge local.APMCBMSFDAS.awsitocore doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic #
1573639924: Connecting bridge awsitocore (a25u2v2hl9xg94-ats.iot.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883)
1573639924: Error: Unable to load CA certificates, check bridge_cafile "c:/Program Files/cert/AmazonRootCA1.pem".
1573639924: OpenSSL Error: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
1573639924: OpenSSL Error: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
1573639924: OpenSSL Error: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
1573639924: Warning: Unable to connect to bridge awsitocore.
```

I have this setup in my mosquitto.conf

```
connection awsitocore
address a25u2v2hl9xg94-ats.iot.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:8883
topic # both 0
bridge_cafile c:\Program Files\cert\AmazonRootCA1.pem.ca
bridge_certfile c:\Program Files\cert\4d8a02e78f-certificate.pem.crt 
bridge_keyfile c:\Program Files\cert\4d8a02e78f-private.pem.key
```

If anybody knows how to bridge AWS to local mosquitto, please drop a setup here.

Comment: Have you looked at why mosquitto doesn't like your `bridge_cafile`?

Comment: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/3764